# I am a beginner js coder trying to make a ping pong game against a computer opponent, but the ball goes right through the paddle

Tags: javascript

this is a link to my code: https://editor.p5js.org/codewithp5/sketches/usjxxu-1n
my problem is that when the ball hits the paddle it goes right through it without bouncing off of it. Please look at my code and notes and tell me how to fix this. thank you? please do not edit my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close. The issue is in your collision checking. On line 35, you're checking

```
circleX==372.5
```

but you want to check

```
circleX>=372.5
```

When calculating collision detection it's best to avoid using '==' as the value of circleX will probably never be exactly 372.5.

Comment: I changed circleX==372.5 to 375>=circleX>=372.5 (I added it had to be less than 375 so when the ball is behind the paddle it doesn't glitch out or make something unexpected happen), but I had the same problem, as shown on https://editor.p5js.org/codewithp5/sketches/dfWXJhn82 where I changed circleX=372.5 to 375>=circleX>=372.5 on line 35.

Comment: Unchain the inequality so it reads "375>=circleX && circleX>=372.5". Chaining the inequality is actually evaluating " 375>=circleX" first, which javascript says is true (rightfully so), then it compares "true >= 372.5", which is false so the check fails.